# Android webview - edit image with native image editor

Tags: android, reactjs, webview

I have a react.js web app, and an android (java) app that servers my web page as a webview.
The web page has in memory several (dynamic) images as base64 text.
I would like to allow the user to edit those images using native photo editor and get the base64 text of the edited photo.
So I have an `<input type='file'>` tag in react, and I am trying to create an `ACTION_EDIT` intent in `onShowFileChooser`. My problem is that I could not find how to send the base64 text of the image from the web app (react) to android java code. Non of the `fileChooserParams` attributes seem fit for that.

Would appreciate some guidance as for the validity of solution that I have chosen and how it could be achieved.

Comment: Very few Android devices have an image editor. Fewer still will honor `ACTION_EDIT`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Don't know how prevalent that is, but I have tried a xiaomi redme node and a samsung phone. Both did

Comment: I would be open to a free react package that lets you edit photos, There are some packages that let you draw over an image, but I could not find any where I would not have to implement many features by myself (e.g. undo and redo, circles, freehand, arrows, text. And a good ux for all of that).